# docker nginx django gunicorn mariadb not serving static files in production

Tags: nginx

`Through Docker, we would like to test the local environment for Janggo, nginx, gunicorn, and mariadb and place them in the final awsec2 environment.

However, css and js cannot be applied to web pages because nginx failed to read static files during deployment testing in the local environment.

Through Docker, we would like to test the local environment for Janggo, nginx, gunicorn, and mariadb and place them in the final awsec2 environment.

However, css and js cannot be applied to web pages because nginx failed to read static files during deployment testing in the local environment.

The first is the structure of the django project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsnLR.png)

The following are docker files.

```
FROM python:3.11.5

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

WORKDIR /app/

# 먼저 requirements.txt만 복사
COPY requirements.txt /app/

# 의존성 설치
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# 나머지 소스 코드 복사
COPY . /app/

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# 모델 경로 복사
COPY mainapp/models/shape_vgg16_process1.h5 /app/mainapp/models/shape_vgg16_process1.h5
COPY mainapp/models/ensemble_soft_model_poly.h5 /app/mainapp/models/ensemble_soft_model_poly.h5
COPY mainapp/models/scalp_model1.hdf5 /app/mainapp/models/scalp_model1.hdf5
COPY mainapp/models/scalp_model2.hdf5 /app/mainapp/models/scalp_model2.hdf5
COPY mainapp/models/scalp_model3.hdf5 /app/mainapp/models/scalp_model3.hdf5
COPY mainapp/models/scalp_model4.hdf5 /app/mainapp/models/scalp_model4.hdf5
COPY mainapp/models/scalp_model5.hdf5 /app/mainapp/models/scalp_model5.hdf5
COPY mainapp/models/scalp_model6.hdf5 /app/mainapp/models/scalp_model6.hdf5

EXPOSE 8000

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

CMD ["gunicorn", "makemeuppro.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Next is Docker-Composite.yml.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn makemeuppro.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles/
      - media_volume:/app/media/
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  dbdata:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:

The following is the nginx.conf file created under the nginx folder.

worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        include mime.types;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://web:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /static/ {
            alias /app/staticfiles/; # 이 경로는 Docker 컨테이너 내의 정적 파일 디렉토리와 일치해야 합니다.
        }

        location /media/ {
            alias /app/media/; # 이 경로는 Docker 컨테이너 내의 미디어 파일 디렉토리와 일치해야 합니다.
        }
    }
}
```

Next up is settings.py .

```
# 미디어 파일 설정 (사용자 업로드 파일)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
```

I don't think I can find the css file on the web console as follows.

The web page console displays the following error message.
Failed to load resource. Server responded with state of 404 (not found)`

Please help nginx find the static file.